# как узнать статистику выполнения программы при компиляции gcc?

Tags: linux, c, macos, компиляция, gcc

gcc 1.c,например, можно как-нибудь узнать время выполнения, память? линукс/мак

Comment: с временем разобралась, можно использовать time ./a.out, а как лучше с памятью? и может есть что-то что выведет все срау

Comment: и при чём здесь программа *gcc*?

Comment: может все таки хочется узнать время компиляции и сколько компилятор захотел памяти? а может просто человек на питончике или другом скриптовом языке пишет

Comment: считала, что могут быть какие-нибудь параметры у gcс позволяющие это все определить сразу, похоже что нужно использовать другие утилиты, но какие найти не могу, help time выдает всего одну опцию -p

Comment: а зачем это? тестить олимпиадные задачи?

Comment: @KoVadim, да, именно это и хочется узнать

Comment: @KoVadim, не олимпиадные, но да, на django пишу простой онлайн компилятор, который должен мне статистику тоже возвращать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В линуксе есть встроенная в баш команда time, а есть полноценная утилита, которая может многое. Запускать ее нужно обычно вот так

```
/usr/bin/time ./a.out
```

правда ее вывод немного "нерепрезентабельный" и странный. Но ее можно обучить:) там есть специальный параметр для форматирования вывода. Но сделаем больше и сделаем его "json подобным".

```
/usr/bin/time -f "{ size_kb=%M, time_s=%e}" ./a.out
```

%M - это в килобайтах RSS, это часто и называют "сколько максимально потребляла моя програма". Но это очень-очень-очень спорная штука, как считать потребляемую память.

в документации есть много-много разных параметров, смотрите, подыскивайте нужные именно Вам.

Comment: огромное спасибо, как раз и видела эти %M и тд, но не поняла как использовать, help time показал что опция всего одна -p. спасибооо